# How to fix 'ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package'

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, relative-import

I use PyCharm and I'm trying to import a class/module from a script into another script.

My two scripts are in the same directory:

```
>|-my_directory

>>|--script_A

>>|--script_B
```

script_A:

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 1

    # some other methods
```

script_B:

```
from script_A import *

# some other code
```

But the issue is, if I run script_B there is an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    from script_A import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

So why this doesn't work? Why is there an error? And how can I fix it?

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Comment: Can you post a pic of the run configuration in pycharm?

Answer (score 1):

Script_A and Script_B are in the same dir. So you can directly import Script_A with `import Script_A` even `import Script_A.*** as XXX`